# Bluetooth: high quality audio recording on Android possible?

Tags: android, bluetooth

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco%28%29), BT classic can only record audio with 8 kHz bitrate and a single channel.

Since there are numerous bluetooth headsets on the market with stereo microphones, I cannot believe there's not alternative to BT Audio with SCO. A2DP seems to do a much better job but is not bi-directional, i.e. can only used for playback and not recording if I'm not mistaken.

Is there an alternative that is compatible with Android versions below 13 (where BLE Audio is available)?

Please forgive me if this is a stupid question, I'm new to the field